# Is typing "powered logs" in this way (eg, $\log^4_{5}66$) wrong?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I was typing some powered logarithms as the answer to my questions on my paper.

My friend saw them and told me that I can't write them that way.

I had written: $\log^4_{5}66$, but my friend told me that I should have written it like this: ($\log_{5}66)^4$.

We write for example $\sin^2x$. But can't we use the same pattern for logarithms?

Comment: You can. Some might find it confusing, but it's routinely done in many research papers. It might be worth reminding the reader of what it means, in case you think there may be some ambiguity.

Comment: Just don't do it with exponent $-1$, or in any context where it would be interpreted to mean $\log^2x = \log \log x$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Can you please explain why should I avoid do it with the exponent $-1$?

Comment: Just as $f^{-1}(x)$ means the inverse function and not $\frac1{f(x)}$, we use $\sin^{-1}x$ to mean the inverse of the sine function and not $\frac1{\sin x}$, even though we use that intermingled with the $\sin^2x=(\sin x)^2$ notation. This exponent notation is therefore ambiguous - it means how many times the function is applied or straightforward exponentiation of the result of the function. Which one is meant depends on context, including the value of the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No typing "powered log" is completely fine. However do notice that people just started logarithm might find it confusing. Thus I advice you to use $(\log_{5}66)^4$ instead of using $\log^4_{5}66$ to avoid confusion to youngster.